# Share an existing photo on my wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way with Facebook Graph API explorer to share on my wall an existing picture having the ID of this pic?

I tried to POST on "me/feed" a "picture" (name) with value "url_of_image" but it doesn't work.

I only want to share on my wall a picture of a page :)